# Who or what created the Galactic Barrier in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In Star Trek, there exists a field of negative energy, known as the [Galactic Barrier](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Galactic_barrier). Later when the Enterprise-D was thrown into a different galaxy, however, they did not experience the barrier. Such a barrier, to a society capable of warp travel, would seem to be a form of containment. Is it ever explained who (or what) made this barrier, and why?

Comment: Within the main canon, No. Within the EU, [it was the Q](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_barrier#Apocrypha).

Comment: You've linked to Memory Alpha in your question. What precisely are you wanting to know that isn't already covered?

Comment: @Richard If there's any info not found there. It's a wiki; it is likely outdated.

Comment: A quick glance at the [wiki history](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_barrier?action=history) indicates that it was updated only a few days ago, and pretty continuously since the page was created

Comment: "most" of us find memory alpha, accurate and up to date. more so then the majority of other wikis out there. Especially if the excerpt from memory alpha tags the episodes its referencing

Comment: @Himarm A shame the only thing covering it is in Star Trek's EU.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In strict canon, nobody knows.

[In extended canon](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Galactic_barrier):

> Greg Cox's [Star Trek: The Next Generation - Q Continuum](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_-_Q_Continuum_(novel_series)) novels state that the galactic barrier was in fact created by the Q Continuum as a method of preventing the powerful being known only as "[0](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/0#0)" from returning to the Milky Way Galaxy, from which he was banished for his destruction of the Tkon Empire. These novels also explain that the telepathic powers that occur as a side effect of exposure to the barrier in telepaths are caused by the power of the Q that exist in the barrier, while those who develop a god complex are 'infected' by the presence of 0, who constantly attempts to affect beings on the other side to give himself access to the galaxy once again.